# Substring of line that contains x and does not contain y

Tags: regex, notepad++, dreamweaver

I'm trying to search and replace HTML code to add missing ID attributes based on the existing name attribute. Searching the internet, I've managed to cobble together the following:

Search for:

```
name=("(.*?)")
```

Replace with:

```
id=$1 name=$1
```

This works perfectly in Dreamweaver's search and replace or Notepad++ by changing the `$` to `\` in the replace string.

What I have been unable to accomplish is a little filtering. I'd like to ignore lines that already have an id attribute and possibly another condition or two. We're going to eyeball each replace so what I have is livable but I'd really appreciate some help to make it more efficient.

Comment: Please share some samples along with expected outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you must only treat tags that haven't an id attribute, you need to ensure that the id attribute is not present from the begining to the end of the tag. To do that, you can use this search replace:

> **search:** `(<\w+\s+(?:[^ni>]|\B[ni]|n(?!ame\s*=)|i(?!d\s*=))*)(name\s*=\s*("[^"]+")(?:[^i>]|\Bi|i(?!d\s*=))*>)`
>      **replace:** `$1id=$3 $2`

The idea is to use character classes to forbid the name or id attribute and the end of the tag until the target attribute *(for the first non-capturing group)* and until the end of the tag *(for the second non-capturing group)* after the target attribute.

**Note:** this pattern doesn't deal with single quotes or no quotes at all, but it is possible to do it replacing `name\s*=\s*("[^"]+")` with `name\s*=\s*["']?([^"'\s])["']?`. In this case the replacement pattern becomes `$1id="$3" $2`. It's a basic way to manage quotes for attributes but it should work.

**Glossary:**

`(?:...)` non-capturing group

`\w` word character class: *equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`*

`(?!...)` negative lookahead: *not followed by*

`\B` non-word boundary: *limit between two characters from the `\w` class or between two characters that are not from the `\w` class*

**[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3C%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3A%5B%5Eni%3E%5D%7C%5CB%5Bni%5D%7Cn%28%3F!ame%5Cs%2a%3D%29%7Ci%28%3F!d%5Cs%2a%3D%29%29%2a%29%28name%5Cs%2a%3D%5Cs%2a%28%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%22%29%28%3F%3A%5B%5Ei%3E%5D%7C%5CBi%7Ci%28%3F!d%5Cs%2a%3D%29%29%2a%3E%29&i=%3Cinput%20name%3D%22octave%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cspan%20name%3D%22jean%22%20id%3D%22louis%22%3E%3Cimg%20name%3D%22igor%22%20src%3D%22%2Figor.png%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E&r=%241id%3D%243%20%242)**